# Why does it say that vp and pf are undeclared when they're both in the struct node?

Tags: c, undeclared-identifier

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h> 

int mms;

int ps;

int rp;

struct node{

int *pf;
int *vp;
} *pt=NULL;

void enter_params(){
    printf("Enter main menmory size(words):_\n");
      scanf("%d",&mms);
 printf("Enter page size (word/page):_\n");
      scanf("%d",&ps);
printf("Enter replacement policy(0=LRU, 1=FIFO):_\n");
      scanf("%d",&rp);
}

void mapVirtualAddress(){
int VA;
int offset;
int tag;
int numEntries;
int k;
int pa;
int i;
i=0;

printf("Enter virtual memory address to access:_\n");
      scanf("%d",&VA);
tag = VA/ps;
offset = VA%ps;

while((i<numEntries)&&(pt[i].vp!=vp)&&(pt[i].vp!=-1))
    i++;
if(i==numEntries){
    pf = pt[0].pf;
    for(k=0; k<numEntries-2; i++)
        pt[k] = pt[k+1];
    pt[numEntries-1].vp = vp;
    pt[numEntries-1]pf = pf;    
    printf("Page fault!");
      }
    else if(pt[i].vp==-1){
        pt[i].vp = vp;
        pt[i].pf = i;
    printf("Page fault!");
    }
    else{
        pa = pt[i].pf*ps+offset;
        }
        if(rp == 1){
            printf("Do nothing");
            }
        else{
            while((k<numEntries-1)&&(pt[i+1].vp!=-1)){
                pt[k] = pt[k+1];
                k++;
            }
            }
            }

void printPT(){
    int i;
    pt[i].vp;
    pt[i].pf;
    while((pt[i].vp!=-1)&&(i<pt[i].vp)){
        printf("VP %d --> PF %d;",vp,pf);
        i++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for help, make it as easy as you can for somebidy to help you. 
You could have added a comment where it says that.

Now the answer:
They are both declared within a struct. You can not use pf or vp directly, you have to declare a variable of the struct and then use them via the struct.

In your example via `pt->pf` or `pt->vp` (once you have assigned pt of course.

And here `pf = pt[0].pf;` the pf is no where declared, which the compiler tells you about.

Furthermore, numEntries is never assigned, so your code produces undefined results.

Please post code that is somewhat runable, otherwise it is very hard to help you!

hth

Mario